# rosrun does not work after sourcing my own catkin workspace

Tags: bash, ros, catkin

I'm following the [ROS-tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingPackage) and I am facing the following behavior after creating my own package:
If try to execute any installed package (e.g. `any_package`), I get the following error:

```
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named <any_package> below /opt/ros/kinetic/share/<any_package>
[rosrun] Found the following, but they're either not files
[rosrun] or not executable:
[rosrun]   /opt/ros/kinetic/share/<any_package>
```

Any help?

**EDIT:**
If I execute `catkin_find --without-underlays --libexec --share <any_package>`, it gives me the following output:

```
Multiple packages found with the same name "my_package":
- my_new_package/my_package
- my_new_package/my_package_2
```

Comment: Please be more specific! What OS do you use? How does your workspace look like?

Comment: Plain Ubuntu 16.04. The workspace is exactly the same as in the tutorial.

Comment: Your link is to a long list of tutorial steps/tasks. Can you provide a more specific link to the exact part of this tutorial you are having problems. This should make it easier for others to help you figure out your problem.

Comment: Sure, I've updated the link!

Comment: Could you please execute the following command after you've sourced your workspace: `catkin_find --without-underlays --libexec --share <any_package>`

Comment: Sure, it gives `Multiple packages found with the same name "my_package" ...`. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you have a tainted workspace.
I assume that you've just copied the `my_package` to `my_package_2` without editing the `package.xml` file in `my_package_2`.
It is not really mentioned in the [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingPackage), since it assumes that you use the proper commands which creates a manifest file with a unique package name.
Just edit the name-tag as follows:

```
<name>my_package</name>
```

to

```
<name>my_package_2</name>
```

in the corresponding folder.

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as correct if it was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

```
You have to make sure you edit CmakeLists.txt according to your compile version, c++ executable declaration & Specify libraries to link a library

Below are step step modification and then run catkin_make before running your project:

step 1
add_compile_options(-std=c++11)

step 2
## Declare a C++ executable
## With catkin_make all packages are built within a single CMake context
## The recommended prefix ensures that target names across packages don't collide
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}_node src/myproject_node.cpp)

step 3

## Specify libraries to link a library or executable target against
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_node
   ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
 )
```